# NullPointerException при getResourses() в RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android

В чем моя ошибка?
Я хочу получить массив строк из ресурсов в адаптере, передаю контекст:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyHolder> {
Context context;

public RecyclerAdapter (Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
String [] _names = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array._names);
```

Или так:

```
public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {
   public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
   super(base);
   }

 public String[] getCategoryName(){
 String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array._names);
 return names;
 }
```

и в адаптере

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyHolder> {
Context context;

String[] _names = new MyContextWrapper(context).getCategoryName();
```

И в обоих случаях получаю NPE в **getResources().getStringArray(R.array._names);**

Strings.xml:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">noyify</string>

<string-array name="_names">
    <item>Pic1</item>
    <item>Pic2</item>
    <item>Pic3</item>
    <item>Pic4</item>
    <item>Pic5</item>

</string-array>
```

На всякий случай стектрейс примера с враппером:

```
03-15 14:44:38.497 8153-8153/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.vadik.noyify, PID: 8153
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vadik.noyify/com.example.vadik.noyify.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.vadik.noyify.MyContextWrapper.getCategoryName(MyContextWrapper.java:16)
at com.example.vadik.noyify.RecyclerAdapter.<init>(RecyclerAdapter.java:22)
at com.example.vadik.noyify.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1:
Не передавайте контекст, используйте тот, что уже есть в RecyclerView.
В холдере сделайте:

```
public class YourHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public Context mContext;

    public YourHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mContext = itemView.getContext();
    }
}
```

Таким образом, вы можете работать с контекстом, который получен от вью холдера.

Update: 
Вариант 2: сразу передавайте готовый массив в конструктор адаптера. Вот прямо из активити.